# How to select the name of the table in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm using a UNION and a LIMIT to select the earliest occurence of a type of table row from multiple tables. I need a record of which table satisfied the query in the result set.

Is there a way of doing something like:

`SELECT id, someField, tableName FROM someUnknownTable WHERE someConditions = true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select your `tableName` as a constant value:

```
Select id, someField, 'Table1' As tableName
From table1
Union
Select id, someField, 'Table2' As tableName
From table2
```

The second alias (`As tableName`) can be omitted.